# How to tell SMF that a service really is online?

Tags: solaris, smf

This seems trivial, but I have a service in Solaris 10 that's running but SMF thinks it isn't.

I could probably get SMF to have the right status by stopping and then starting the service, but in this case the service is SSH, which means I have to be at the system console to restart it.

How can I tell SMF, "This service is really running; please move it into 'online' status?"

---

**Edit**: Some information requested about the ssh service:

The output of `/usr/lib/ssh/sshd -d | head -1`:

```
debug1: sshd version Sun_SSH_1.1
```

The output of `` ptree `pgrep sshd` ``:

```
453   /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
  11456 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
    11459 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
      11461 -tcsh
  20521 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
    20524 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
      20526 -tcsh
        22145 ptree 11459 20521 11456 20524 453
```

The output of `` pargs -e `pgrep sshd` ``:

```
11459:  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
envp[0]: EDITOR=vi
envp[1]: GROUP=wheel
envp[2]: HOME=/home/philadm
envp[3]: HOST=radiance
envp[4]: HOSTTYPE=sun4
envp[5]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[6]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/lib/$ISALIST:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib
envp[7]: LOGNAME=philadm
envp[8]: MACHTYPE=sparc
envp[9]: MAIL=/var/mail//philadm
envp[10]: MANPATH=/opt/csw/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/man:/storage/lang/man:/usr/local/ssl/man
envp[11]: OSTYPE=solaris
envp[12]: PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/nsr:/usr/sbin/nsr:/opt/hpnpl/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
envp[13]: PWD=/var/log
envp[14]: REMOTEHOST=bastion2.example.com
envp[15]: SHELL=/bin/tcsh
envp[16]: SHLVL=1
envp[17]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.45 45010 22
envp[18]: SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.45 45010 192.168.1.5 22
envp[19]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
envp[20]: TERM=xterm
envp[21]: TZ=US/Eastern
envp[22]: USER=philadm
envp[23]: VENDOR=sun

20521:  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
envp[0]: EDITOR=vi
envp[1]: GROUP=wheel
envp[2]: HOME=/home/philadm
envp[3]: HOST=radiance
envp[4]: HOSTTYPE=sun4
envp[5]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[6]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/lib/$ISALIST:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib
envp[7]: LOGNAME=philadm
envp[8]: MACHTYPE=sparc
envp[9]: MAIL=/var/mail//philadm
envp[10]: MANPATH=/opt/csw/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/man:/storage/lang/man:/usr/local/ssl/man
envp[11]: OSTYPE=solaris
envp[12]: PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/nsr:/usr/sbin/nsr:/opt/hpnpl/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
envp[13]: PWD=/var/log
envp[14]: REMOTEHOST=bastion2.example.com
envp[15]: SHELL=/bin/tcsh
envp[16]: SHLVL=1
envp[17]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.45 45010 22
envp[18]: SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.45 45010 192.168.1.5 22
envp[19]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
envp[20]: TERM=xterm
envp[21]: TZ=US/Eastern
envp[22]: USER=philadm
envp[23]: VENDOR=sun

11456:  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
envp[0]: EDITOR=vi
envp[1]: GROUP=wheel
envp[2]: HOME=/home/philadm
envp[3]: HOST=radiance
envp[4]: HOSTTYPE=sun4
envp[5]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[6]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/lib/$ISALIST:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib
envp[7]: LOGNAME=philadm
envp[8]: MACHTYPE=sparc
envp[9]: MAIL=/var/mail//philadm
envp[10]: MANPATH=/opt/csw/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/man:/storage/lang/man:/usr/local/ssl/man
envp[11]: OSTYPE=solaris
envp[12]: PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/nsr:/usr/sbin/nsr:/opt/hpnpl/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
envp[13]: PWD=/var/log
envp[14]: REMOTEHOST=bastion2.example.com
envp[15]: SHELL=/bin/tcsh
envp[16]: SHLVL=1
envp[17]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.45 45010 22
envp[18]: SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.45 45010 192.168.1.5 22
envp[19]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
envp[20]: TERM=xterm
envp[21]: TZ=US/Eastern
envp[22]: USER=philadm
envp[23]: VENDOR=sun

20524:  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
envp[0]: EDITOR=vi
envp[1]: GROUP=philadm
envp[2]: HOME=/home/philadm
envp[3]: HOST=radiance
envp[4]: HOSTTYPE=sun4
envp[5]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[6]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/lib/$ISALIST:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib
envp[7]: LOGNAME=philadm
envp[8]: MACHTYPE=sparc
envp[9]: MAIL=/var/mail//philadm
envp[10]: MANPATH=/opt/csw/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/man:/storage/lang/man:/usr/local/ssl/man
envp[11]: OSTYPE=solaris
envp[12]: PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/nsr:/usr/sbin/nsr:/opt/hpnpl/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
envp[13]: PWD=/var/log
envp[14]: REMOTEHOST=bastion2.example.com
envp[15]: SHELL=/bin/tcsh
envp[16]: SHLVL=1
envp[17]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.45 45010 22
envp[18]: SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.45 45010 192.168.1.5 22
envp[19]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
envp[20]: TERM=xterm
envp[21]: TZ=US/Eastern
envp[22]: USER=steveadm
envp[23]: VENDOR=sun

453:    /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
envp[0]: EDITOR=vi
envp[1]: GROUP=wheel
envp[2]: HOME=/home/philadm
envp[3]: HOST=radiance
envp[4]: HOSTTYPE=sun4
envp[5]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
envp[6]: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/lib/$ISALIST:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib
envp[7]: LOGNAME=philadm
envp[8]: MACHTYPE=sparc
envp[9]: MAIL=/var/mail//philadm
envp[10]: MANPATH=/opt/csw/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/man:/storage/lang/man:/usr/local/ssl/man
envp[11]: OSTYPE=solaris
envp[12]: PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/nsr:/usr/sbin/nsr:/opt/hpnpl/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
envp[13]: PWD=/var/log
envp[14]: REMOTEHOST=cbastion2.example.com
envp[15]: SHELL=/bin/tcsh
envp[16]: SHLVL=1
envp[17]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.45 45010 22
envp[18]: SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.45 45010 192.168.1.5 22
envp[19]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
envp[20]: TERM=xterm
envp[21]: TZ=US/Eastern
envp[22]: USER=philadm
envp[23]: VENDOR=sun
```

Comment: You should be able to issue a restart without interrupting your session as it just stops "new" clients from connecting. That's with *nix though ...Solaris is a different beast.

Comment: On Solaris (and with Sun SSH, which is a lightly-modified fork of OpenSSH), a restart of the service just sends a signal to the sshd process. I'm not brave enough to try stopping the service remotely, just in case it does kill my session. (Also, I'd like to know if there's a correct answer to this, as the next time I might not be able to shut down the service without customers noticing.)

Comment: @NathanC Solaris *is* definitely *nix, Unix even ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service is in maintenance mode, you might just need to run:

```
svcadm clear service
```

or perhaps:

```
svcadm refresh service
```

If the service is reported as offline but is actually usable, you should investigate further to understand why smf thinks otherwise. Start by looking the service logs (look at the following command output to know where they are):

```
svcs -xv service
```

Edit: The issue is the main `sshd` which is running (pid 453) has not been launched by smf but by philadm, not to mention with an unsupported environment. In any case, smf cannot "adopt" this sshd. You might just kill it (`kill 453`)  and smf should be able to start the ssh service. Both current ssh connections shouldn't be affected by this kill.

Comment: `svcs` reports that the service is offline, even though `sshd` is running and accepting connections. I don't know how it got into this state. When I run `svcadm start sshd`, it calls `sshd`, which exits immediately (because another instance is already running), so SMF still thinks the service is offline.

Comment: Have you installed an alternate sshd package on that machine ? Please update you questions with the output of these ksh/bash commands as root: `ptree $(pgrep sshd)` and `pargs -e $(pgrep sshd)`

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Answer updated !

Comment: After killing the master process, SMF restarted `sshd`.  You also answered the thing I really wanted to know about this with, "In any case, smf cannot 'adopt' this sshd."